# 'styled()' function drops 'component' prop support

Tags: typescript, material-ui

Look at the following code:

```
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ButtonBase from "@material-ui/core/ButtonBase";

const MyButton = styled(ButtonBase)({ color: "red" });

const App = () => (
  <>
    <ButtonBase component="a" />
    <MyButton component="a" />
  </>
);
```

`ButtonBase` is working as [expected](https://material-ui.com/ru/api/button-base/#props), but suddenly there is an error from Typescript, telling that there is no 'component' prop on `MyButton`.

[image: error]

Is this correct? What is the workaround for this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just extended ButtonBaseProps and overrode some needed props in it. It's a very plain workaround for the problem and it is requiring to manually add missing props to the interface, but it will do for now.

```
import ButtonBase, { ButtonBaseProps } from "@material-ui/core/ButtonBase";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export interface MyButtonProps extends ButtonBaseProps {
  component?: any;
}
interface MyButtonAsLinkProps extends MyButtonProps {
  component: "a";
  href: string;
  target?: "_blank";
  rel?: "noopener noreferrer";
}

export const MyButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "red",
  },
})(ButtonBase) as (props: MyButtonProps | MyButtonAsLinkProps ) => React.ReactElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HOC you could use `withStyles` from MaterialUI

I created a sandbox [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-cloud-unmh2)

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ButtonBase from "@material-ui/core/ButtonBase";

const styles = {
  MyButton: {
    color:'red'
  },
};
const MyButton = ({ classes, children, ...rest }) => <ButtonBase className={classes.MyButton} {...rest}>{children}</ButtonBase>;

const MyButtonStyled = withStyles(styles)(MyButton);

const App = () => (
  <>
    <ButtonBase component="a">ASD</ButtonBase>
    <MyButtonStyled component="a">DSA</MyButtonStyled>
  </>
);
```

Comment: This is hardly a good solution, since in current version it's just [removes](https://capella.pics/43520c2f-3278-49b6-ac3a-eb702b98b75c.jpg) all prop-checking from component.

Comment: @Snelsi it's just deconstructive `props`, you can write it without it `const MyButton = props => ...` Don't know if it helps you, I saw the `TypeScript` tag now after your comment. I don't use TypeScript

Comment: Actually, this may be a temporary workaround for the problem without need of loosing all props-check.
I added following interface to MyButton, and error message went away:
`interface MyButtonProps extends ButtonBaseProps { component: any; }`